# Reclassifying slope using ArcGIS raster calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, error-000539

I have a slope raster in degrees and would like to reclassify it the layer with the raster calculator.

my criteria: slope between 15 & 20 receive a 1
slope greater than 20 receive a value of 2
all other values receive a zero

```
Con(("noury_slope" >= 15) & ("noury_slope" <= 20,1,0)),Con("noury_slope" > 20,2,0)
```

get this error

```
ERROR 000539: Error running expression: rcexec() 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in rcexec
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 3806, in BooleanAnd
    in_raster_or_constant2)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 53, in swapper
    result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 3803, in Wrapper
    ["BooleanAnd", in_raster_or_constant1, in_raster_or_constant2])
TypeError: expected a raster or layer name

Failed to execute (RasterCalculator).
Failed at Mon Aug 21 10:42:24 2017 (Elapsed Time: 0.30 seconds)
```

I want to do this query in one step. whats wrong with my syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate your parameters.

Try this:

```
Con("noury_slope" > 20, 2, Con(("noury_slope" >= 15)  & ("noury_slope"<= 20), 1,0))
```